# Comparison: "half-plate armor+dexterity+Medium Armor Master feat" and "plate armor". What is the best?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, armor

I want to make a melee fighter, and I'm strugling on the choise of my armor for the build. I put my stats on my character when I'll define all I want to do for my build, so let's suppose that I can have the stat and race you want to define which armor is better (I'll use the standard point buy rule).

I think that I'll use duelist for my fighting style, and have a shield. The objectif of the build is to take as much as possible the less amount of damage as possible while having a good amount of damage output and, if possible, be usefull out of combat too. The DM said that de campaign is designed to go up to level 20.

I hesitate between taking an half plate and a plate armor whenever I can (which will be replace with their magic version whenever I can, my DM allowing us to buy magic items with gold).

On one hand, Plate give the best base AC, 18, and have a strength and stealth restriction that force me to play only in one way, but have the advantage that the only cost on the character sheet to have some point in strength.

On the other hand, half-plate give 15+dex mod (max 2) AC, which is less and with the same stealth restriction, but with the Medium Armor Master feat I can have the same amount of armor, and I can play stealthy if I need to. Plus investing in dexterity seams to me a better choice regarding that dexterity have a far more usefull saving throw, far more skills affected, and give bonus on damage and attack rolls with some weapons.

On my point of view half-plate look far better, but on most of the online build that I found, they use Plate armor and not half-plate, so I think I miss something crucial.

Is my list of Pro/Con miss something? Is there a reason that make most of the online build choose one and not the other? Or, to simplify : What is the best option between "half-plate armor+dexterity+Medium Armor Master feat" and "plate armor"?

---

Since I don't find a way to order my priorities for the build without make it look like too mechanical, I'll put them their:

1- High AC
2- High saving throw 
3- decent amount of damage
4- Be usefull out of combat

My point is that half-plate + high dex + Medium Armor Master feat look like it match all of this point, while Plate armor don't, but since Almost all build I found online prefer Plate armor, I think I miss a point, so I want to know what I miss by comparing both options.

Comment: Hey, what kind of fighting style are you going to play?

Comment: How do you measure what the best build is? At the moment this seems a bit too broad to be properly answered.

Comment: I think I going to use Defense for the AC, or duelist for the bonus damages

Comment: @BBeast It is somehow more a Pro/Con oriented question, because it look like I miss something obvious, and I want to know what.

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what your actual goal is in order to determine 'best'. Do you want the highest AC? Do you want AC but are willing to sacrifice it for stealth? Do you want something else? Can you prioritize your priorities?

Comment: I'm going to leave this question closed for now as we still do not have a clear criteria to judge what is 'best'. Consider editing your question to address the following: Are you seeking to become a very tanky character that can hold the frontline with high AC? Or a tanky character that has high AC and saves? Are you looking to have damage output along with high AC? Although you've not allotted stats, do you have point-buy criteria or an array to use? What level of play is being considered? I'd recommend providing an answer to all of these to get the best answer.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical done it ^^

Comment: @NautArch I tried to edit one more time to clarifie as much as I can.

Comment: Your priority list still doesn't really make sense, and it's all over the place.If High AC is your priority, then that's it. You say Saves, but what saves? What does decent amount of damage mean and why does it matter when talking about armor? What does being useful out of combat mean and what is the relationship of that to Armor? You still also didn't answer the questions on how you generate stats (although I"m not sure if that's totally necessary), what level of play you are and are going to, and if you are wanting to use STR or DEX based weapons.

Comment: I think we may be tackling the wrong problem here. Rorp seems more interested in knowing the general rule for optimization to design a character instead of a more specific advice for a concrete character.

Comment: @MrTakeru I'm not sure there is a general rule. It's going to vary depending on criteria and priority. It may still be stackable to go through the iterations and possibilities, but it seems broad at first blush.

Comment: If you are adding Medium Armor Master to your half plate, you should compare to Heavy Armor Master or some other feat on your full plate for a more fair comparison. HAM means anything with a basic d6 damage die has to beat your AC and then also has a 50/50 chance of dealing no damage anyway (but this becomes less effective at higher levels).

Answer (score 6):

## It really depends on what character you are trying to build.

Most builds dump STR or DEX depending on what they are focused on. For example, frontline characters with spells like Paladins need 3 high stats (STR, CON and CHA) so investing in DEX is not always possible, and giving up an ASI for a feat is really hard for them without tons of planification.

Also, take into account that Medium Armor Master doesn't increase AC of Medium armor, it raises the limit on DEX, so you have to invest another ASI on DEX to be worth it, whereas Heavy Armor Master gives you non-magical damage reduction AND increases your STR, virtually losing only half an ASI.

## Does that mean medium armor is bad?

No, of course not. I'm in fact a fan of medium armor over heavy armor because of initiative, saves, skills... DEX is a really good (if not the best) stat to invest in, and now Finesse is free, and characters like Barbarians take more penalties than normal if they wear heavy armor.

If you compare 5e with 3e or 3.5e, non-light armor have some sweet adjustments for making it more playable in general, but medium keeps having some niche spot because heavy DEX builds will always take light and non heavy DEX builds usually dumps it.

Having said all that, which option is better is very subjective, because is not a choice between having 17/18 AC, but between being able to invest in DEX or not. As a rule of thumb, I would say:

- Heavy Armor: Paladins, Most non-archers Fighters, Clerics with proficience (domain dependant), Multiclass builds into any of these classes with plans to get at least 16 STR.
- Medium Armor: Non-Naked Barbarians, the rest of the Clerics, Some
  non-archer Rangers.
- Light Armor: Everyone else but Monks, Wizards and Sorcerers.
- None: Monks, Wizards and Sorcerers.

Take into account that, if you want to be a sneaky tank, Breastplate armor is 14+DEX (max 2) but doesn't have dissadvantage. Also, wearing a Shield and no armor works with Duelist, but not with Defence.